# SKPhysicsBody composition?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, composition, skphysicsbody

How can I create a concave SKPhysicsBody?

My guess is to create a composite node that consists of multiple convex bodies. Can I "stick" them any other way that create an SKPhysicsJointFixed between each?

Comment: Is there a problem with SKPhysicsJointFixed?

Comment: It "tears" above a given force impact. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to wait a short while - I can't say it explicitly, but there's an intriguing new `SKPhysicsBody` method if you look at pre-release docs at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/) and search for "iOS 7.1 API Diffs".

---

There is another way - you can simply create new `SKNodes`, add your new nodes as the children of your target composite node, and attach convex `SKPhysicsBodies` to these child nodes.
 EDIT: this will only work for non-dynamic constituent bodies, if you just want to detect contact/collision on a  concave composite one that's static.

Comment: It was my guess too, but would them "stick" this way? Probaly still remains the need for joint.

Comment: You're correct - it only worked for me because my child bodies were non-dynamic (I was just testing for contact on a static concave body). Dynamic bodies will indeed fall apart. Can you please post your code where your fixed joint "tears"?

Comment: Wow, really, `+[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:]` seems promising to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create two or more SKPhysicsBody variables using convex paths, then create a union of these paths using the initializer [SKPhysicsBody.bodyWithBodies](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithBodies:). This union can be concave.